# How to make ESP8266-1S module work on Arduino Uno?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi

I currently have an Arduino Uno with an ESP8266-1S. However I can't make them work... I use the ESP8266wifi.h library and its connection functions do return a true (returns true when received a valid IP), but I can't find it in my network...

When I send 'AT' ending with CR and NL on 115200 baud I still don't get a response.

Also, do I have to connect RX with RX and TX with TX or RX to TX and vice versa?

And also, do I need any converters? Because now I directly connect the TX and RX to the Arduino's TX and RX.

So this is how my board looks like:
[image]

So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you sending the "AT" from code running on your Uno or are you sending it from the Serial Monitor (or any other terminal program running on your computer)?

Comment: I send it using the serial monitor from Arduino

Comment: [ESP8266 WiFi module and 5V Arduino connection](http://iot-playground.com/blog/2-uncategorised/17-esp8266-wifi-module-and-5v-arduino-connection)

Comment: you need to short rst to gnd on the uno to bypass the avr and use uno as an "ftdi"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> do I have to connect RX with RX and TX with TX or RX to TX and vice versa?

If you want to do serial communication between a sketch running on the Arduino and the ESP8266 you must connect the RX pin on the Arduino to TX on the ESP8266 and the TX pin on the Arduino to TX on the ESP8266.

If you want to do serial communication between the Serial Monitor on your computer through the USB port on the Arduino to the ESP8266 you must connect the RX pin on the Arduino to TX on the ESP8266 and the TX pin on the Arduino to RX on the ESP8266.

TX stands for **Transmit** and RX stands for **Receive**. So it makes sense that you should connect the transmit pin to the receive pin in the first case. But why connect transmit to transmit and receive to receive in the second case? The reason is that you are not communicating between the main microcontroller (ATmega328P on the Uno) and the ESP8266. You are communicating between the USB-serial chip on the Uno (usually ATmega16U4 on the official Arduinos or CH340 on the clones) and the ESP8266. The main microcontroller is not being used at all, you're just using the Arduino as a bulky and inconvenient USB-serial adapter.

In fact some people will go so far as to remove the ATmega328P from their DIP Unos for this purpose. The RX pin on the USB-serial chip is connected to the TX pin on the main microcontroller as well as the TX header pin and vice versa for TX pin on the USB-serial chip. This means by connecting the ESP8266's TX pin to the TX pin on the Uno's header you are actually connecting it to the RX pin on the USB-serial chip. I would highly recommend getting a USB-serial adapter made for this purpose rather than trying to use an Arduino. You can buy FTDI FT232 or CH340 breakout boards on eBay or Aliexpress for < $2 USD w/ free shipping.

> do I need any converters? Because now I directly connect the TX and RX to the Arduino's TX and RX

This is actually two questions. Let's address the easy one first. The TX pin of the ESP8266 is going to put out around 3 V. Even though the ATmega328P is running at 5 V this will still be seen as a high so no level conversion on that pin is necessary.

Now for the question of whether it's needed on the ~5 V level from the Arduino to the ESP8266 RX pin. There's a lot of disagreement on the question of whether the IO pins on the ESP8266 are 5 V tolerant. We certainly know that it's possible to connect the ESP8266 to 5 V levels as there are many projects published online that do this but the question is will this will shorten the life of the ESP8266?

The datasheet for the ESP8266 does not say the inputs are 5 V tolerant. There is a statement on the ESP8266 forum from a member of the Espressif (creator of the ESP8266) staff:
http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?t=1145

> We donot recommend you to apply 5V to IO.

We have a comment from someone on Facebook named "Teo Swee Ann" who appears to be the CEO of Espressif:
 https://www.facebook.com/groups/1499045113679103/permalink/1731855033731442/?comment_id=1732364133680532

> i can reply officially here: it is 5V tolerant at the IO. while the supply voltage is at 3.3V.

So there is conflicting information and none of it has been presented in the most official manner, such as actually putting it in the datasheet. One thing we do know for sure, you will not harm the ESP8266 with 3.3 V levels. So the safest option is to avoid giving it 5 V inputs. However, as you are currently struggling just to get the most basic communication working the extra complication introduced by adding level shifting circuitry may not outweigh the possibility of reducing the life expectancy of your ESP8266.

Comment: Thank you for your great answer ,but I still have some questions: for serial com, do I have to connect the TX and RX both to the RX of Arduino? Or is it a typo? And when I try to upload the code, I get the espcomm_upload_mem failed error... And can I give the module 5V supply voltage for testing, or is that a total no-go?

Comment: That was a typo. I've fixed it now. Thanks for pointing that out. It should be TX-TX, RX-RX for communication from Serial Monitor to the ESP8266.

Comment: Regarding the espcomm_upload_mem failed error. Are you trying to upload code directly to the ESP8266 using the Arduino IDE? That's fine but be aware If you do that you will overwrite the AT firmware and will no longer be able to use the ESP8266wifi library on the Uno or control it from the Serial Monitor using AT commands unless you reinstall the AT firmware. Note that there is a library named ESP8266WiFi included with the Arduino ESP8266 core that has a similar name but is completely different from the ESP8266wifi library.

Comment: Regarding 5 V supply voltage. You should never power the ESP above 3.6 V and I wouldn't go much above 3.3 V to be safe. The discussion about 5 V tolerance is only for the IO pins. There has never been any confusion regarding the maximum supply voltage, that is stated clearly in the datasheet. Some ESP8266 boards do have voltage regulators that allow them to be powered by 5 V but they reduce the voltage to the ESP8266 to 3.3 V. The ESP-01 type module shown in your wiring diagram does not have the voltage regulator.